# Nativescript Vue: Is there a way to use highlighted or active pseudo selectors on non-button elements?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a row of boxes made from `StackLayout` and I'm looking to changing the background color when only when a finger is pressed on the box.  I tried using `:highlighted` in CSS but it seems to only work with button elements.

EDIT:

I actually had this but it applies it to all my boxes since it's in a v-for :

```
<StackLayout v-for="item in items" orientation="horizontal">
   <StackLayout v-bind:class="{ 'color': bgColor }" 
   @touch="hoverOver($event)">
   </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>

////
hoverOver: function(e) {
   if (e.action == "down") {
      this.bgColor = true; 
   } else if (e.action == "up") {
      this.bgColor = false;
   } 
}
```

Comment: You may apply a class with background color upon touch and remove it back on touch end.

Comment: Hi @Manoj -- I actually tried that at first but it applies the color to all my boxes since it's in a v-for loop.  I made an edit above to show what I tried.

Comment: Then it must be a bug with code, can you post it.

Comment: You should set the bgColor property on each item and instead bind the color class to item.bgColor.

Comment: It's the flaw with your logic. You have one variable bind to every element, and when you change it of course all will be affected.

Comment: @Lochlan and Manoj:  thank you both -- how would I bind the color class to an individual instance of the object ( item.bgColor )?  Wouldn't I need multiple variables then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is to have a flag in each item

**Example**

```
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                <Label v-for="item in items" :text="item.title" :class="[item.selected ? 'selected' : '', 'h1 p-15']"
                    @touch="hoverOver($event, item)">
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            hoverOver: function(e, item) {
                item.selected = e.action !== "up" && e.action !==
                    "cancel";
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                items: [{
                        title: "A",
                        selected: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: "B",
                        selected: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: "C",
                        selected: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: "D",
                        selected: false
                    }
                ]
            };
        }
    };
</script>

<style scoped>
    .selected {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: interesting!  Thanks for your continued help in this community @Manoj